# How does $\ln(x)$ behave when raised to itself?

Tags: logarithms

How does $\ln(x)^{\ln(x)}$ behave? Can it be shown to be  theta to any simpler, more familiar function? (polynomial, exponential, log-linear)?

Comment: The domain should be $(1,\infty)$, yes?

Comment: yes, naturally otherwise it is undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x>1$,

$$(\ln x)^{\ln x}=e^{\ln x\ln\ln x}=x^{\ln\ln x}$$

so it is greater than every polynomial, but lesser than every exponential.

Comment: I was not sure if this would answer your question, thanks for the approval.